# Does swallowing food remains between teeth spoil sawm (fasting)?

Tags: sawm, food

Does swallowing food remains between teeth spoil sawm (fasting)? Please mention the case when it is done *intentionally*, *unintentionally*, and *intentionally because you couldn't manage to remove the food remainings.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Brief speaking, swallowing intentionally the thing (food…) which has
  remained between the teeth, it spoils or breaks the fast (Sawn)
- (But concerning swallowing unintentionally, it seems can be related
  to eating unintentionally which doesn’t break or spoil the fast.)
- Eventually, as the last past: Whoever who intends to fast, it is not
  necessary for him/her to use tooth-pick before the Azan. But
  his/her fasting would be broken if s/he knows (sure) that the
  remained food which have remained between the teeth would be
  swallowed in case that s/he doesn’t use the tooth-pick. / Even as
  wajib precaution (Ehtiat) it ought to be redo (do its Qaza) even if
  it has not been swallowed. (But it would be wajib if it has been
  swallowed) / notice: these are related to the case of being sure
  that the food will be swallowed in the case that you do not use the
  tooth-pick. But in the case of probability is not like that and
  doesn’t seem…

(According to Imam Khomeini and Imam (ayatollah) Khamenei) as two Shia Marja'al-Taqlids)

---

But I guess the view of Sunni brothers is pretty the same that eating or swallowing unintentionally won’t break the Sawn. (Although eating intentionally will spoil the Sawn)

---

**References:**

- [rahrovanevlaiat.mihanblog.com](http://rahrovanevlaiat.mihanblog.com/)
- [www.aviny.com](http://www.aviny.com/ahkam/resalehsafigolpaygani/resale88.aspx)

Comment: Jazaka Allahu khayran for the beneficial answer!